# Can I make pasta with atta flour?

Tags: baking, pasta

I have purchased a bag of atta flour and am wanting to make pasta - is this flour suitable? And is atta a self raising flour or plain flour?

Answer (score 6):

[Atta usually refers to durum flour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atta_flour) (often whole wheat) used in Indian/South Asian cuisine. It is  used for indian flat breads like [chapati](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chapati), [roti](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roti) and [naan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naan). Where it normally isn't self-rising, you can find special self-rising naan atta (that contains some kind of leavening agent), but it will be then labeled as self rising or at least special naan atta.

That said, like any **durum flour** most attas are well-suited for [making dry pasta](http://www.flourbin.com/cgi-bin/pnDbDetail.cgi/display%3a%3afaqs%3a%3a%3a%3a%3a:33%3a%3auser%3a%3a%3a%3a) (which does not require eggs cause it has high enough gluten contents).

I have used atta flour for eggless pasta myself, it worked well and it was easy to roll it really thin to prepare lasagna sheets and ravioli.

Comment: Good answer but +1 for the epic mustache!

Answer (score 1):

Yes! You can, in fact, it is used in India to make fresh pasta like Gujarati dal dhokri.